TensorFlow Inference Slowed Down with Python 3.12 - Issues with EagerExecute and EagerTensor
I'm updating a FastAPI service that performs TensorFlow-based predictions. After upgrading to Python 3.12, I noticed a significant slowdown in prediction performance.
I made some improvements, but I'm currently stuck with performance bottlenecks related to EagerExecute and EagerTensor. Below is a screenshot from TensorBoard after profiling the inference
Profiling results
The code for inference is the next one:
    @tf.function
    def inference_with_tf_function(self, input_data: tf.float32):
        """
        Perform optimized inference using tf.function.
 
        Args:
        model (tf.keras.Model): The Keras model to be used for inference.
        input_data (tf.Tensor): Input features for the model.
 
        Returns:
        tf.Tensor: The predicted output.
        """
        return self.model(input_data, training=False) 
 
    def predict(self, features: np.ndarray):
        input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(features, dtype=tf.float32)
        return self.inference_with_tf_function(input_tensor).numpy()

I'm running TensorFlow 2.17 (legacy mode with Keras v2). The inference executed on CPU.
I'm looking for advice on how to fully leverage TensorFlow's graph execution and avoid Eager execution bottlenecks during inference. Any insights on how to optimize for GraphTensor usage or ideas on improving performance under these circumstances would be much appreciated.
I’ve already tried setting:
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)
But that hasn’t helped improve performance.

Can you utilize  tf.function's tracing to understand which parts of your code are causing graph recompilations @tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
